# Tabu: factors of cell width

Tags: width, tabu

When I use factors of a variable in `tabu`'s cell description, the result is not what I intended. For example in the following code, the middle cell is not half the width of the others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcommand \myWidth {60mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu}
    {|p{\myWidth}| p{.5\myWidth}|p{\myWidth}|}a & b & c
    \end{tabu}  
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: Result]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a length register:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newlength \myWidth
\setlength\myWidth {60mm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu}
    {|p{\myWidth}| p{.5\myWidth}|p{\myWidth}|}a & b & c
    \end{tabu}  
\end{document}
```

Your original would just work by macro expansion so

```
p{.5\myWidth}
```

would be the same as

```
p{.560mm}
```

which is legal, but smaller than you intended.

Comment: Or `.5\dimexpr\myWidth\relax`

Comment: @egreg yes or perhaps less intrusive `\newcommand \myWidth {\dimexpr60mm\relax}` But a length register is simpler now e-tex has lots of them.